# Spring batch : Pairing with a lot of data for one line

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, reader, large-data-volumes, pairing

I am using Spring batch.

I have a reader with an input file that includes N lines with same format.

I read the file with chunk size and commit-interval at 100.

I want to match each row with occurences from the database.

For a single occurrence, I can appaired a large volume of data from database.

For example : GT;123;456;PICK

This previous record can refers to more than 600 occurrences of my database.

As a result, my program ended with an out of memory.

How can I ensure commit interval at 100 ? Do you have any recommendations in order to ensure size commit interval ?

Thanks by advance for your anwser.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen even without Spring Batch. You need to make sure to allocate enough memory to hold a chunk of items. If you are enriching items from another data source, you need to make sure there is enough memory for items + additional data.